# What to do when we need another table and a model for it, in case we have already applied the database first approach? (.NET Core, MVC)

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Whether the steps are the same as for the first time? Is it good to use the -force command to change the old state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Scaffold-DbContext command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) or [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) could help generate code for a DbContext and entity types for an existing database.

If you'd like to generate entity types for specific tables, you can set `-Tables <String[]>` parameter, like below.

[image]